Gauss–Bonnet Theorem for rectangular surface with rectangular holes: is the right hand side always $0$?
I want to use the Gauss–Bonnet theorem for a non-Euclidean rectangular 2D surface with discrete curved boundaries that has rectangular holes with discrete curves.

I know that:
$$ 
\oint k_g \, ds + \int K \,dA = 2\pi\chi - \sum \theta_{\mathrm{ext}} 
$$
Now for no holes, $\chi=1$, and external angles add up to $2\pi$. If I add a rectangular hole, the integrals on the left hand side changes, but on the right hand side now $\chi=0$, external angles of the exterior boundary is still $2\pi$, and the exterior angles of the interior boundary is $-2\pi$. So the right hand side is still zero.
And if we add up more rectangular holes, the deficit by the $\chi$ term gets compensated by the new exterior angles of the rectangular holes. Then is it true that for rectangular holes, we will always get right hand side equals $0$, no matter how many holes we add up, and the only change will be  on the left hand side?

It's not necessarily true that the interior angles of a quadrilateral add up to $2\pi$ in non-Euclidean space. In general, if you introduce a four-sided hole then all terms in the equation will change, and since the $\chi$ term will have reduced by $2\pi$, the change in the others must sum to compensate for that. However, we cannot predict in general how this compensation will occur, only case-by-case.
For instance, if the four sides are geodesics, then the change in the line integral term will be zero (as $k_g=0$ along the new boundary section), and
$$-\int_{\Omega} K\;dA+\sum\theta_{\Omega,\;ext}=-2\pi$$
where $\Omega$ is the region we removed.

Thank you very much!
Just so that I understand correctly:
(a) If it is flat+boundaries are geodesic - the sum of exterior angles is equal to $2 \pi \chi$
(b) If it is flat, but boundaries are non-geodesic - the sum of exterior angles is $2 \pi \chi$ offset by the geodesic curvature integral
(c) If it is neither flat nor the boundaries are geodesic - then we'll have contributions from the Gaussian curvature integral too

@FahimBinSelim Precisely! Those aren't the only conditions, though: we can equate "flat"$\iff K|{\Omega}=0$ and "geodesic boundary segments"$\iff k_g|{\partial\Omega}=0$. Notice that these values being zero aren't necessarily implied by their integrals being zero - on a flat surface, you can have squiggly boundaries of your four-sided hole, but so long as they meet at right angles, then the integral $\oint_{\partial\Omega} k_g;ds$ will still be zero (confirmed by computing the other values).

That was really helpful. Thanks a lot! :D
